# Python: Why does have 2^-n work for n>52 and not 1+2^-n-1?

Tags: python, numpy, math, floating-point

I'm pretty new to python, and I've made a table which calculates `T=1+2^-n-1` and `C=2^n`, which both give the same values from `n=40` to `n=52`, but for `n=52` to `n=61` I get 0.0 for `T`, whereas `C` gives me progressively smaller decimals each time - why is this?

I think I understand why `T` becomes 0.0, because of python using binary floating point and because of the machine epsilon value - but I'm slightly confused as to why `C` doesn't also become 0.0.

```
import numpy as np
import math
t=np.zeros(21)
c=np.zeros(21)
for n in range(40,61):
    m=n-40
    t[m]=1+2**(-n)-1
    c[m]=2**(-n)
    print (n,t[m],c[m])
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, should've been more clear - I'm not looking to fix this, I'm just curious as to why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

The "floating" in floating point means that values are represented by storing a fixed number of leading digits and a *scale factor*, rather than assuming a fixed scale (which would be *fixed* point).

`2**-53` only takes one (binary) digit to represent (not including the scale), but `1+2**-53` would take 54 to represent exactly. Python `float`s only have 53 binary digits of precision; `2**-53` can be represented exactly, but `1+2**-53` gets rounded to exactly 1, and subtracting 1 from that gives exactly 0. Thus, we have

```
>>> 2**-53
1.1102230246251565e-16
>>> 1+(2**-53)-1
0.0
```

Postscript: you might wonder why `2**-53` displays as a value not equal to the exact mathematical value when I said it was exact. That's due to the float->string conversion logic, which only keeps enough decimal digits to reconstruct the original float (instead of printing a bunch of digits at the end that are usually just noise).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between both is indeed due to floating-point representation. Indeed, if you perform `1 + X` where X is a very very small number, then the floating-point representation sets its exponent value to 0 and the precision is ensured by the mantissa, which is 52-bit on a 64-bit computer. Therefore, `1 + 2^(-X)` if `X > 52` is **equal** to 1. However, even `2^-100` can be represented in double-precision floating-point, so you can see C decrease for a larger number of samples.

Comment: And why am I wrong exactly? I have not talked about multiplication, which is different.

Comment: Well I meant `1 + X` with `X = 2^(-Y)` where  `Y > 52` but I think everyone understood that. I'll modify

Comment: The new version is wrong for example for `X = 52.1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Sorry for being stupid though, why can 2^-100 be represented if the precision is only 52-bit?

Comment: The format of the floating-point type was is not determined by whether the machine is “32-bit” or “64-bit”. You can have both 32-bit and 64-bit floating-point formats on a 32-bit machine or a 64-bit machine.

Comment: In the IEEE 754 basic 64-bit binary format, the significand (the preferred term for the fraction part, rather than mantissa) is 53 bits, not 52. 52 bits are used to encode the significand, in combination with the exponent, but, when discussing what values can be represented, the 53-bit mathematical significand is more relevant than the 52-bit encoding field.

Comment: @T.L: You must see floating-point numbers like scientific representation. If I write 1.4454398398*10^12, you can see the number of fractional numbers (10) as the precision, and the 12 as the exponent value. If I do 1+X, with X very small, the number can be for instance 1.0000000002*10^0, but if X is smaller, it will end being 1.0000000000*10^0. However, I can have something very small but with a high precision: 2.5948579389*10^-15. The scale of the number is expressed by the elevation of 10 here.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: you are right considering the first 1 of the mantissa is implicit.